# Kendall's tau or Kruskal Wallis Test?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, ranking, kruskal-wallis-test, kendall-tau

I have data which is not normally distributed. Each participant ranked six actions in order of preference (so this is ordinal data right?) I want to see whether there is a significant difference in their preferences depending on the group they are in. As there are more than three groups, I believe that I could conduct a Kruskal Wallis (as this is a non-parametric test) however I also think that a Kendall tau may be appropriate (but as my data is groupings -categorical against rankings-ordinal, I'm not sure correlation is the right thing to do).

I'm still not entirely sure if I am clear with any to analyse this so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you believe my answer is wrong (I could be wrong), please tell me what I went wrong. I might edit my answer or even delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an application for Friedman Test, which is a non parametric test for repeated measurement.

Let's look at the Wikipedia:

> n wine judges each rate k different wines. Are any of the k wines ranked consistently higher or lower than the others?

- You have participants, the example has wine judges
- Your participants rate 6 items, the wine judges rate k wines

Does that sound familiar?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't believe my data to be repeated measures as I  would like to compare the ranking between groups and each of the 100 participants (I had slightly more than this) are separated into 4 different groups (so this would make it non-repeated right?) So say if participants in Group 1 significantly preferred item 1 over the others, compared to the other groups. I don't think Friedman would fit with this?

Comment: @Dragonfly Yes, it is. When a participant rates something for 6 times in a row, it's repeated.

Comment: @Dragonfly Data for each participant can be broken into 6 rows. One for each item. This is how marketing professional code their data.